# Can employer read message sent via Skype / Slack etc

Tags: employment

a friends company is using Slack for communication between the team members. Slack is basically like Skype.

Recently a few people got fired as the employer read the conversations they were having and deemed it as inappropriate for the work place.

My question is, what legal background does the employer have in reading the messages. Are they legally allowed to do this?

Thanks for all your help